# Bake multiple Armature animations within one file with IK

Tags: animation, workflow, armature, three.js

I am just working on a small WebGl project based on the three.js framework and I am just trying to switch between several animations I made in blender. I know therefore I need to bake my animations since they have inverse kinematics.

Let's say I have two animations in my blend.file, a walk cycle and a run cycle. Now I want to bake both of these animations and export it into one collada file. How do I do that?

The problem is, when I bake my first animation, I lose my IK for the second one and can't bake it.

Help is much appreciated!

Thanks so far!
Marten

Comment: Good luck exporting/importing COLLADA. I spent a month trying to do what you're doing and couldn't.

Comment: As a workaround, could you duplicate the file/animations and bake one animation in one file and one in the other, then append the baked animations back into one file?

Answer (score 1):

So, I did some more research and I found out that the blender collada exporter isn't able to export multiple animations within one file.

To fix my IK problem, I simply duplicated my armature several times. Than I used 1 armature/ animation to bake every animation. After that I was able to use my main armature connected to my mesh to select all the baked animations. That works pretty good, but nevertheless it's too bad collada doesnt support multiple animations.

For now I am going with JSON.